# Switching focus according to a window's position on the screen

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm a programmer who uses a large monitor, with multiple windows visible alongside each other. E.g I might have an IDE, a text editor, multiple terminals and a web browser open and visible at the same time.

I want to be able to switch focus between these windows using the arrow keys. I don't like the CMD-Tab shortcut because it is constantly reordering the windows - I never know what window I will get. Instead, I want to shift focus between the windows according to their position on the screen.

For example, if I have Chrome at the left of the screen and a terminal at the right, pressing e.g "CMD-Option-Right arrow" will shift the focus rightwards from Chrome to the terminal, and vice versa.

I understand that these shortcuts aren't built in to Mac OS. I'm looking for ideas about how to develop them. Would it be possible to write a script that obtains the position of each running window and switches focus accordingly?

Comment: `Would it be possible to write a script that obtains the position of each running window and switches focus accordingly?` Yes. Is that the only question you wanna ask?

Comment: For example, in AppleScript it is quite easy to get the size and position of any window, http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/11.html and then you'd use `activate` https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW60 when detecting a keypress https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255758/applescript-detect-key-press-by-user-alternatives That would be a couple of minutes of work for any programmer who knows AutoIt but that won't work on MacOS. sadface.jpg

Comment: @Gantendo obviously I'm also asking how to do it

Comment: Thanks for pointing out AppleScript, that looks like a goer :)

Comment: Well, this is one way how to do it with AppleScript. It is probably also possible with another programming language but I do not know which programming languages you are familiar with. You need 3 basic thing: the ability to detect the size and position of a window, the ability to detect keypresses, and the ability to switch focus. AppleScript is pretty easy but you'll have to use a workaround to get it to detect keypresses (there are many ways to achieve that goal, just google "applescript detect keypress" for more options)